# Copied file physics settings missing

Tags: animation, physics

I finished all the constraints and timing settings on a 10-second 24-fps animation at work, with rotations, (hinge, motor) images and textures. Setting to include external files was checked. I copied the whole folder and brought it home to finish with rendering this weekend.
1. NONE of the physics settings came with it. 
2. NONE of the transparency/opacity animation timings came across.
All other stuff did show up. Same Blender version (2.78a), same computer capabilities. Did I miss something, like a setting to copy physics?

Comment: "Setting to include external files was checked." What setting? Where?

Comment: File / External Data / Automatically Pack into .blend.